# makefile putting objs in separate directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Why does

```
$(OBJDIR)\%.o:$(SRDDIR)\%.s
    $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)\%.o:$(SRDDIR)\%.c
    $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

gives warning (says ignoring the first rule)
where as

```
%.o:%.s
    $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o:%.c
    $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

works fine but I will have all my sources and objs in the same directory.
I would like to put the objs (generated from assembly files and c files) in a separate directory( and I am running make on windows).

Comment: Use a four space indent to get `monospaced output`. Also, generally, you should be using `$(CC)` to invoke the compiler, not `$(GCC)`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `SRCDIR` instead of `SRDDIR`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using forward slashes ("/") instead of backward ones ("\").

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` flag of GCC determines where the output file are made.

So this may work if you change:

```
%.o:%.s $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

**TO**

```
%.o:%.s $(GCC) -c -g -I$(SRCDIR) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o myoutputdir/$@
```